# How to read MSISDN from sim card by SIM_IO?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I need to read MSISDN in android, but we must use .c to finish it.
I open a socket to send `RIL_REQUEST_SIM_IO` to ril. Here is the log.

```
D/RILC    (  106): [0004]> SIM_IO (cmd=0xB2,efid=0x6F40,path=3F007F10,1,4,30,(null),pin2=(null),aid=(null))
...
D/RILC    (  106): [0004]< SIM_IO {sw1=0x90,sw2=0x0,ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0891684125205260f5ffffffffff}
```

Did I use the right parameters (P1 = 1, P2 = 4, P3 = 30)?

And how can I get the mobile phone number by response?

Thank you!☺

Comment: How did you actually use that request?

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2):

What is your confusion here? You wanted to know what you told the card? All this information is in ISO 7816-4 and a few other specs, but here's the details of what you did:

You sent a read record command to the SIM (0xB2) 
You asked for the Path:

```
3F00 -> (MF)
7F10 -> (DF_TELECOMM)
6F40 -> (MSISDN)
```

You set parameters:

```
P1 (record)                   = 1  (record 1)
P2 (reference control)        = 4  (this mean use record number set in P1)
P3 (Le meaning bytes to read) = 30 (bytes)
```

and you got back success (SW stands for status word, you got SW1/SW2 = 0x9000 which means success) and the data (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0891684125205260f5ffffffffff)

Checkout [E.164](http://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/ob-lists/icc/e164_763.pdf) on parsing your MSISDN.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that mean the data  (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0891684125205260f5ffffffffff)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that mean the data  (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0891684125205260f5ffffffffff) contains MSISDN in it? I'm not sure because it looks different with usual phone numbers. It's too long. Can you take an example please, just like: 0xfff...fff parsing into +86130...

Comment: startinng at 08 you have:
08 - number of bytes for the TON/NP & Number
91 - TON/NPI split into nibbles, it means TON is 1 (international), NPI is ISDN (a 'normal' number)
68 41 25 20 52 60 F5 - this is the nibble swapped phone number

Answer (score 0):

the data (0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0891684125205260f5ffffffffff) yes it contains MSISDN

----08 = means the Length of dial no

----91 = means MSISDN Internatioal dial No

the rest (684125205260f5) value u nid to swap it side by side of each 1 byte. example 68 swap 86, 41 swap 14...so on then u will got the MSISDNnumber.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps some1 later on:
Encoding can be found on TS 51.011. File is called EF_MSISDN. Its identifier is 6F40.

MSISDN is preceded by its length, then the TON/NPI. It is also in a BCD inverted format